# Make a CSS rounded dotted line

Tags: css, border, responsive

I would like to create a rounded dotted line in CSS like the picture.
I tried the "border dashed" but the edges are square.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please include a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of your code

Comment: You might need [`border-radius`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border-radius)

Answer (score 4):

Use background:

```css
.box {
  height:10px;
  background:
    radial-gradient(circle closest-side,red 98%,#0000) 50%/40px 100%,
    linear-gradient(90deg,red 50%,#0000 0)             50%/80px 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>
```